# Log application running times on Windows

Tags: windows, logs

I'm looking for an application that keeps track of all other processes and records the time frames during which they are being used on Windows 7.

The data I'm interested in is:

- What process was launched
- When process was launched
- When it stopped
- For how long it worked
- (bonus) What parent process started the child process

It would be nice to be able to visualize it over a 24-hour, month or a year long time frame graph to get a better picture of how often, when and for how long specific processes are run on a Windows machine.